# how to check if a window feature is set in Android 2.x

Tags: android

I want to check if a feature is set. I can use [hasFeature](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#hasFeature%28int%29) , but it's for API 11 and above, and what's confusing me is [getFeatures](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#getFeatures%28%29) is protected. which means I can not call in my activity code without use refection hack.

Is there a standard way to check window features on Android 2.x?

Comment: @Elemental Wrong question perhaps? This doesn't mention admob at all.

Comment: Why I am getting "This question may already have an answer here:"? window feature is not related to admob

Comment: possible duplicate of [getWindow().hasFeature() on API < 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925708/getwindow-hasfeature-on-api-11)