# getWindow().hasFeature() on API < 11

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I need to check if the overlay feature has been set on an `ActionBarCompat` instance. The `getWindow().hasFeature()` method is only available on API 11 and up.

How can I check the feature on API < 11 ?

**EDIT:** Based on the comment, the `getFeatures` method should be available from API 1 but it is protected scope and I need to access the feature from another class. The `hasFeature` method, the one I need to use, on the other hand is API 11 and above only. This is what Android Studio shows me and the app crashes on a 2.3.3 device.

[image: Image from AS]

FYI, the activity class used here is a custom class that extends `ActionBarActivity` from the ActionBarCompat library. Don't know if that should make a difference.

Comment: hey getFeature() method is available from API 1  check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#getFeatures()

Comment: getFeatures() is a protected method. I need to access the feature from another class. hasFeature() is the public version which this question was about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access `private` methods using [The Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

```
boolean hasFeature(int feature) {
    Window window = getWindow(); //get the window instance.
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) { // if we are running api level 11 and later
        return window.hasFeature(feature); //call hasFeature
    } else {
        try {
            Class c = window.getClass();
            Method getFeatures = c.getDeclaredMethod("getFeatures");//get the getFeatures method using reflection
            getFeatures.setAccessible(true);//make it public
            Integer features = getFeatures.invoke(window, null); //invoke it
            return (features.intValue() & (1 << feature)) != 0; //check if we have the feature and return the result.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;//in case invocation fails with any reason
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't reflection slow on Android ?

Comment: Well, relatively speaking yes it is a little bit slower, but this is just one call, how slow it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

Action bar is introduced in android 3.0 (API level 11), but if you want your app to support action bar in older versions too, then use Support Library to make it compatible with older versions (Android 2.1 and above)

Comment: That is exactly what I'm using but the support library doesn't have an implementation of this method